# Solving a PDE in 3 variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am a physicist by trade, but I as this is a pure maths question I thought I'd ask it here.

I need to solve the following PDE for a project:

$$\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial t^2} + \beta \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = a \Big(\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial y^2} \Big)   
+ b - \sin(P), $$
where $\beta$, $a$ and $b$ are all constants. I am trying to numerically solve this PDE over a rectangular domain, with $x$ running from $0$ to $W$ and $y$ running from $0$ to $L$. I am unsure where to begin, after first looking into MATLAB's PDE toolbox, I found that it can only solve PDEs that fit into the categories of elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic or eigenmodes, which I believe this equation does not. The conditions at the boundaries are given by the Dirichlet condition $P = 0$ and the Neumann condition $\nabla P = 0$.

My main question is, are there any software platforms on which I could solve this PDE numerically?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: The equation is a semilinear hyperbolic PDE (assuming $a\neq 0$).  You probably need to do some coding yourself (it looks like PDE toolbox only do linear ones)

Comment: I think you can start by solving the equation by ignoring b-Sin(P). It should be amenable to Separation of Variables. Once you have these solutions, I think you can use principles from Perturbation Theory to factor in the extra terms.

Comment: Oh right, thank you. Do you know of any good examples of such an approach? I've not encountered solving a PDE via a perturbative approach before (or at least never done it myself).